# How to normalize data with 2D features and shape of (Samples, X,Y)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have data shape of **(400,93,32)**. Now I want to standardize the data with 0 mean and unit variance. How should I do it?

In which direction should I standardize ? should I take the mean and variance of each row or column or treat **93 x32** as matrics? I have tried using Sklearn function **StandardScaler** and it takes the input in the form of **(n_samples,n_features)** and I have **(n_samples,Dim_1,Dim_2)**. I tried scaling it row-wise like this **[n_samples,0,1,3,...n, : ]** and am not sure whether am doing it the right way.

your guidance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row-wise scaling wouldn't make sense, think of 2 rows:

```
[20,4,5] , [200,1,5]
```

If we applied row-wise scaling then the first row would be transformed according to that row and similarly the second row :

```
[1,0.20,0.25] and [1,0.005,0.025]
```

Which has failed to capture the relation between values within the same column, what if 5 was the highest possible value in the 3rd column, then 5 should have been 1, however when applying row-wise scaling the value 5 in 3rd column changes on each row and fails to hold the meaning of the information

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this 32 is actually time axis. Even then I should standardize column wise? Here columns do not represent features rather rows do.

Comment: scale along the axis which represents a particular feature